# Python mayavi: Adding points to a 3d scatter plot

Tags: python, 3d, plot, mayavi

I'm writing a python application to simulate the motion of particles in 3-space. I'd like to plot the  positions for each step, updating the plot as the app runs, keeping the past positions on the plot.

I'd like to do this with mayavi, but as far as I can tell, one cannot simply add points to an existing scatter plot, but must add all points in one go. This is not what I want. I want to add a few points at a time without having to keep all past points in memory to redraw them all at each step.

The function I've been looking at is plot3d().

http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.points3d

Any ideas on how to do what I want with python mayavi? Is there another python 3d plotting package that would do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you named your object :

```
mypoints = mlab.points3d(...)
```

You can access at any stage the current traits :

```
mypoint_data = mypoints.mlab_source.get(['points'])['points']
```

and add whatever you want to it (e.g.: you want to add point 0,0,1:

```
mypoint_data = np.vstack((mypoint_data, np.array([[0,0,1]])))
mypoints.mlab_source.set(points=mypoint_data)
```

if you have scalars they also need to be updated using the keyword 'scalars'

```
myscalar_data = mypoints.mlab_source.get(['points'])['points']
...
mypoints.mlab_source.set(myscalar_data)
```

Hope this helps, and works.